# Turn a div tag into a input box

Tags: javascript, jquery, pug

I want to be able to ckick on the h2 in the .editable div and it should change into an input box. Then you can edit it and it will updat the input when you click out of it or press enter. This is what I have for it, i'm stuck:

jQuery:

```
$('.editable').on('click', function() {
  var h3 = $(this)
  var input = $('<input>').val(h3.text())

  h3.after(input)
  h3.hide()

  input.on('blur', function(){

  })
  //blur
  //keyup code 13 -- code 27 reset

})
```

jade: (petty much html)

```
  div.edit-menu-page
    div.title
      h2 Edit Menu
    div.menu-wrap
      div.menu-category
        div.menu-title
          div.editable
            h3 Meat
        div.menu-items
          div.menu-row
            span.item-description New York Striploin
            div.control-items
              span.item-price 10$
              span.delete X
```

.

Comment: Answer from Jeremy Blalock seems to be complete and descriptive, although it takes some time to implement such control from scratch, especially if you need not only simple input field, thus I would suggest using existing libraries that provide functionality for inline editing 

http://webrevisions.com/jquery-plugins/8-best-edit-in-place-jquery-plugin/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically what you want to do is place a form element next to the original element, then when you're done, replace the form element with the original element.

Something like this should work:

```
$(document).on('click', '.editable', function() {
    var $wrapper = $('<div class="editing"></div>'),
        $form    = $('<form action="#" class="edit-form"></form>'),
        $input   = $('<input type="text">');

    // Place the original element inside a wrapper:
    $(this).after($wrapper);
    $(this).remove().appendTo($wrapper).hide();

    // Build up the form:
    $wrapper.append($form);
    $form.append($input);
    $input.val($(this).text()).focus();
});

$(document).on('submit', '.edit-form', function(e) {
    // Don't actually submit the form:
    e.preventDefault();

    var val       = $(this).find('input').val(),
        $wrapper  = $(this).parent(),
        $original = $wrapper.children().first();

    // Use text() instead of html() to prevent unwanted effects.
    $original.text(val);
    $original.remove();
    $wrapper.after($original);
    $original.show();
    $wrapper.remove();
});
```

**Edit**: Here's the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c0fb11qw/1/

Comment: If you want to make it really cool, you can also pull the style attributes like `font`, `width`, etc. of the original element into the input element.

Answer (score 3):

```html
<div contenteditable="true">
  This text can be edited by the user.
</div>
```

full info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick answer for you, http://codepen.io/someyoungideas/pen/mJWLXE. Looks like Jade doesn't play too nice with jQuery with the way your input works because it adds some spacing in the input.

```
$('.editable').on('click', function() {
  var h3 = $(this)
  var input = $('<input>').val(h3.text())

  h3.after(input)
  h3.hide()

  input.on('blur', function(){
      h3.text(input.val());
      h3.show();
      input.hide();
  })
  //blur
  //keyup code 13 -- code 27 reset

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need:

Working JsFiddler: https://jsfiddle.net/t0hjxxgy/

HTML

```
<div class="editable">
    <h3>Edit me</h3>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('.editable').on('click', function() {
    var $editable = $(this);
    if($editable.data("editing")) {
       return;
    }

    $editable.data("editing", true);
  var h3 = $("h3", this);
  var input = $('<input />').val(h3.text())

  h3.after(input);
  h3.hide();

  input.on('blur', function(){
      save();
  })
  input.on('keyup', function(e){
      if (e.keyCode == '13') {
          save();
      }
      if (e.keyCode == '27') {
          reset();
      }
  })

  function save() {
      h3.text(input.val());
      input.remove();
      h3.show();
      $editable.data("editing", false);
  }

    function reset () {
        input.remove();
      h3.show();
      $editable.data("editing", false);
    }
})
```